# Make File Copy Errors Pop Up In Foreground

Tags: error-handling

With Linux copying files at a rate of 40 kilobytes per second for a collection of files totaling about 700 megabytes, it was going to take several hours. I at least put on a youtube video (in full screen) and ended up going to bed. Minimizing the video this morning, I am greeted with a file copying error (splicing error) and asking what to do about it. Well I hit skip. And now I see that I am only 25% of the way through all my files. The system wasted at least 6, probably 7, hours on waiting for my input on what to do with this error.

How do I make linux OS errors (or really any software errors) pop up in the foreground so I know to address them?

Comment: You don't and how would that help when the error occured while you are sleeping? . The error is shown in a terminal and terminal will not force itself to the foreground as it does not know about the question cp asked.  You need to tell cp upfront is can skip if errors occur. There is a command called "yes" that will answer all of cp questions with yes. It also allows for custom replies (if you need an "s").

Comment: @Rinzwind Because I wasn't asleep at the time of the error. I was still conscious and would have seen the error pop up if it popped up instead of popped under. The error is not in a terminal. It's a GUI message. Ever go into a folder, right click a file, and select Copy, then go to a new folder, and select Paste? That.

I have had multiple times with Linux where an error does present in various **GUI** programs where they have a pop-under box for the error. I want to make those pop-up boxes.